# Central limit theorem with Limits?

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, functions, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1,X_2, . . .$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random variables with
> $E[X_1] = 1/2$ and $\operatorname{Var}[X_i] = 2$.

I want to Compute:

$$P\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} (X_1+X_2+...+X_n)/n > 1\right)$$

**My try:**

$P(\lim_{n->\infty} (X1+X2+...)/n > 1) = 1-P(\lim_{n->\infty} (X1+X2+...)/n \leq 1) = 1-P(\lim_{n->\infty} ((X1+X2+...)/n-1/2)\sqrt{2/n} \leq (1/2)/\sqrt{2/n})$

as I know that:  $((X1+X2+...)/n-1/2)\sqrt{2/n}~N(0,1)$ From Central limit theorem. But my problem is the limit inside.

**My Questions:**

1. How can I continue from here
2. Is there a way to solve this exactly without using Central limit theorem?

Comment: Have you learned the strong law of large numbers?

Comment: @SangchulLee I just read about it a little now, can you kindly help me see how it can be used here (it's my first time)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Strong Law of Large numbers:

$$P\left(\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}=1/2\right)=1 \implies P\left(\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}\ne1/2\right) = 0.$$

Since $1/2\neq 1$, we have that $P\left(\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}X_i}{n}>1\right)=0$.